# GitHub - After removed from a repository it doesn't show my contributtions

Tags: github

On my Github profile I did a lot of contributions in private repositories of my previous job.

But, they removed me from their repositories and my contributions graph become almost all blank, as if I never contributed  or sent code with my GitHub account profile (because most of my contributions were in my previous job repositories).

I don't think that this is fair. Other future employers may think that I don't have much experience or contribution because I don't have code to show to them.

Is there a correct way to think about this or solve it? What should I do?

Comment: That's the way Github works. Not much that can be done now. But if you need help with demonstrating experience in your resume, maybe you can ask in a better-suited forum, like https://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Comment: These links might help: [Why are my contributions not showing up on my profile?](https://help.github.com/en/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile) and [Publicizing or hiding your private contributions on your profile](https://help.github.com/en/articles/publicizing-or-hiding-your-private-contributions-on-your-profile). Otherwise, [contact Github support](https://github.com/contact).